# Rearrange BINOM.INV to get probability_s

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there an excel formula that can do this?

I have a few initial variables:

10,000 population, 10% avg success, 1% lower bound

So to get a sort of lower confidence interval I can do BINOM.INV(10000, 10%, 1%) / 10000 = 9.31%, therefore if following performances have a better success than 9.31% then I can assume it was in line with the avg success, if not even better.

I'd like to rearrange this so I can calculate the what the avg success would need to be given a lower confidence interval.

I.e. If I want the lower confidence interval to be 9%, what avg success rate would fit the following: BINOM.INV(10000, ???, 1%) / 10000 = 9% for example.

Comment: I tried to help you out with the following 'Central Limit Theorem' attempt, but the resulting numbers don't make sense: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3i03.png). Can anyone fix the maths?

Comment: regarding the Central Limit Theorem approach check here: [Link](https://bcs.whfreeman.com/webpub/Statistics/tps3e/Statistical_Applets/clt-binomial.html#:~:text=The%20Central%20Limit%20Theorem%20says,probability%20of%20the%20same%20event.)